# Xcode 11.1 Running and Testing On a Device iOS 13.1.2, Setting Breakpoints

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, breakpoints

I have a 7+ year old project file that started with Xcode 4, which has been 
ported to Xcode 5, 7, 8, and 9.2. For all those versions of Xcode there was
a consistent method and behavior of the Run (Play) button and setting and 
stopping at breakpoints.

This is an Enterprise app and I've always had the luxury of actual iPhones 
and iPads to do testing (never needed to use the simulator). We recently had 
to jump from Xcode 9.2 to Xcode 11.1 to support newly bought devices running 
iOS 13. I've always used objective-c.

My problem is with Xcode 11.1. The Run button behaves differently, and 
breakpoints are not causing the program to halt. As far as breakpoints
halting, nothing was changed in project settings relating to the 
numerous accounts I've researched in Stackoverflow for breakpoints to 
be ignored. And it's always worked for me before. As far as the Run button, 
I'm seeing unreasonable behavior. Maybe the two issues are related which 
is why I'm pairing them together.

In previous versions of Xcode, one pressed the Run button which 
resulted in the following:

```
 1. The code was compiled and built when an editing change 
    had been made. 
 2. The newly built app was installed on the device whether 
    or not there was a previous version of the app already 
    residing there. 
 3. The app was then executed and breakpoints were halted
    upon.
```

In Xcode 11.1, the Run button shows a list of apps is provided to 
execute. If my app does not already exist on the device, it does 
not show up on the list. And none of the steps outlined above are 
performed.

This is how I have to now build and run the app on a device using
Xcode 11.1 and iOS 13.1.2

To build the app I go into Product->Build For->Running. That
builds the app which is now just sitting there. To actually get
it installed on the device I have to go back to the Run button
and choose one of the available apps which in my case I choose
"Books". Before Books is started, I can see text in the status
window indicating my app is being installed on the device. Books
is then started and I press the Stop button to kill it. Then I
press the Run button again and see my app on the list. I can
then choose to run it and I see output to the debug window.

However, after my app starts running none of the breakpoints 
I've set are halted upon.

Would appreciate any help you can muster. Is there a method to
compile and build and run an app similar to the old method? And
is there a reason you can think why breakpoints are not being
serviced?

Thank you.
Mike

Comment: If Xcode shows a list of apps to run it usually means you have selected an extension rather than an app as the run target. If your project contains an extension make sure you have selected the app not the extension as the run target.

Comment: Hello Paulw11, Thank you for your reply. I understand what you are saying. I never deliberately set the app as an extension so I hope it wasn't set that way by Xcode. But I double checked the build settings. In the Packaging paragraph, "wrapper extension" is set to "app. In the Build Options paragraph, Require Only App-Extension-Safe API is set to no. I assume assignment for extension is only within those paragraphs, those settings.....

Comment: ....I'm curious about your last sentence where you say make sure to select the app not the extension as the run target. In the "General" settings the executable file is set to the definition $(EXECUTABLE_NAME), whereas other designations for the various bundle identifiers are referenced with (PRODUCT_NAME). If you have any more thoughts I would appreciate it. Thank you. Mike

Comment: I don't even know if you project has an extension. An extension is an additional target; a today widget, a code spotlight extension, a SiriKit extension etc. the behaviour you are seeing is what you get when you want to debug one of those, which is why I suggested it.

Answer (score 0):

Over the many years I've used Xcode, I never had to change the *Scheme* of execution. So I never even understood it's purpose. For some reason, when I downloaded the newest version of Xcode (11.1), it changed the default values for Scheme causing the Run button to launch in a different manner which I described in the post. Perhaps it's due to an extension I'm not aware of in my code dependancies as Paulw11 mentioned. But anyway, here is the way to insure your app will be launched directly and in the debugger:

Product->Scheme->Edit Scheme-> Build Configuration = Debug, Executable is set to "Your App", Debug Execution is set to checked, Launch Automatically is set to checked.

Beware Xcode may change these values when you download a new version.